# how to access browser local storage from jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, browser, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a Jupyter notebook within a cloud based platform. I try to retreive the language information from the web platform but I cannot pass it directly to the sandbox that runs the jupyter kernel. On the other hand this information is hidden in the browser local storage under the `sepal:language` key.

Is it possible from a jupyter notebook, to access the information stored in local storage ?

Comment: May be you can try [this?](https://github.com/jkelol111/localStoragePy)

Comment: I don't want to create a localStorage I would like to read an existing one, I tried the following : `localStorage = localStoragePy('sepal.io') localStorage.getItem('sepal:language')`but get no results

Comment: Not sure if it can be done directly with Python. Selenium drivers can execute JavaScripts, that can read local storage of a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the explainantion found in this [article](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/ipython-notebook-javascript-python-communication/), I came up with the following code cell that do exactly what I need:

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML

javascript = """
<script type="text/Javascript">
        var command = "lang = " + "'" + localStorage.getItem('sepal:language') + "'"
        
        var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
        kernel.execute(command);
</script>
"""

display(HTML(javascript))
```

the language key value is now stored in the python variable `lang` that I can reuse everywhere in my notebook